# 802.11 Authentication frame response - wrong Authentication algorithm detected by Wireshark

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, authentication

Although the title of this question might be a bit complicated, the question is actually very simple:

I am analyzing my 802.11 traffic but the authentication response frame made me confused.

[wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLA7K.png)

As you can see, the authentication response frame sent from my home router towards my smartphone device is telling that the AP is actually using an Open System (0) as the Authentication Algorithm. The fact is that my router is actually using Shared Key - not the OSA. Why does the Authentication frame contain wrong information about the routers authentication mechanism? Or I am doing something wrong?

Cheers,
Marko.

Comment: You're still using WEP? Also, what does the Auth Request frame from the client to the AP ask for?

Comment: It is just a part of the research project to better understand frame communication. Therefore I am observing frame exchange between the client and the AP in different scenarios.

The authentication request have occurred when the client typed in the WLAN password and tried to connect.

Comment: You didn't answer either of my questions. First I'd like to know what wireless security mode you've configured on your AP. Shared Key authentication, at this layer, is a leftover from the bad old days of WEP. All the post-WEP authentication methods (all forms of WPA and WPA2) use Open System Authentication at this layer. So first I'm wondering if your AP is configured for WEP. Second, I would like to see what the previous Authentication frame looked like (the one from the client to the AP, that caused the AP to respond with the frame you showed).

Comment: I've definitely misunderstood the context of your first question, sorry for that. In this case I was using WPA2 so its obvious that AUTH frame response contained Open System (0). Thanks for your explanation, I've used to think that any method (except the OSA) uses Shared Key Authentication. I don't know why, maybe the word 'key' tricked me to think this way. Thanks once again for clarification, problem solved - it was human mistake (like always). :)

Comment: @markojic - If you'd like to protect your management packets, you could purchase a solution that supports 802.11w Protected Management Frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 802.11 standard defined a special Authentication packet format, and requires a successful exchange of 802.11 Authentication packets before a client can become Associated (i.e. joined, connected) to an AP.

That Authentication packet format was only used for WEP, which is now broken and deprecated. Nobody uses it anymore. However, the requirement to do a successful Authentication packet exchange is still in place, so everyone does "Open System" authentication for that special Authentication packet exchange, which is basically a no-op: No authentication at all. Technologies like WPA2 end up doing their real authentication later, after Association, at a higher layer (via eapol-key frames, which are basically Ethernet frames, not low-level 802.11 frames).

One common point of confusion is that old-and-broken WEP had an old-and-broken authentication method known as "shared key authentication", and still-good WPA2 has a still-good authentication method known as "pre-shared key" (PSK). Since both of those authentication methods contain the phrase "shared key", people sometimes get them confused.

I think you may have gotten confused by this legacy baggage in the protocol and the similar names, and you were expecting to see WPA2-PSK authentication happening via the legacy-baggage 802.11 Authentication frames before Association, instead of looking for the eapol-key frames after Association.

Comment: Exactly! I've skimmed through a lot of literature but, somehow, I've missed this important difference between the WEP and WPA/WPA2. However, your explanation helped me to understand this concept better than any book I've read, thanks!